# Position of stress in 3-letter-abbreviation: BBC and DVD

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, word-stress

Book "English pronunciation in use - Advance" [E1] page 40:

[image]

**(1)** the ˌBBˈC

**(2)** He works for the BBˈC.

**(3)** He works for ˈBBC RAdio.

Book "Oxford Word skill - intermediate - 1st edition" [E2] page 237:

[image]

**(4)** DVˈD

Question 1: With `DVD`, it is `ˌDˌVˈD`, why not `ˌDVˈD` as (1)?

Question 2: What are rules for (1) (2) (3). With 3 positions of stress for 1 word `BBC`, I cannot understand when use (1), (2), or (3)?

[E1] https://www.cambridge.org/gb/cambridgeenglish/catalog/grammar-vocabulary-and-pronunciation/english-pronunciation-use-advanced/english-pronunciation-use-advanced-book-answers-and-downloadable-audio?isbn=9781108403498&&format=DO

[E2] https://elt.oup.com/catalogue/items/global/grammar_vocabulary/oxford_word_skills/?cc=global&selLanguage=en&mode=hub

Comment: Do you see Unit 10B as the textbook mentions? What does it have to say?

Comment: This is Unit 10B https://1drv.ms/i/s!AhMAe-fS33VbhbUdX2DaxhL_JQwzOg?e=h0SFep

Comment: I don't know 'why not DV'D'.  How does _Oxford Word Skill_ tell you to pronounce BBC? Maybe the two books have chosen to express it differently. This is something that native speakers don't need to think about.

Comment: Book *Oxford Word Skill*  did not mention *BBC* word.

Comment: There is no difference between DV**D** and D V **D**. Both 3 syllables.

Comment: But the "**B**BC Radio" used the acronym as an adjective. That use changes the emphasis. As per @IMSoP, there is failry even stress. If you needed to emphasize the **Broadcasting** middle B, you'd be right in pronouncing it B**B**C.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Ah, I'd missed that point about using it as an adjective; I think that explains that example, since it talks specifically about stress *shift*.

Answer (score 6):

Somebody may come along later with better sources, but I think the reality here is that acronyms like this are often pronounced with fairly even stress, so marking a "correct" stress pattern is difficult.

In early 20th Century "BBC English", a radio announcer would have paused between each letter, rather than treating it as a word: "This is the [Bee Bee See Home Service](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBC_Home_Service)". Spoken quickly, that might lend a slightly stronger stress on the first B. On the other hand, if you *do* run it together as though it was a word "beebeesee", the natural stress would fall on the last syllable, and therefore the C.

DVD is a much more recent word, and more often spoken as though it was a word, "deevidee" or "deeveedee". The main stress is definitely on the last syllable, but there is probably some variation in how the rest is pronounced. The difference in secondary stress marker on the middle syllable is probably referring to speakers either pronouncing a full "ee" sound, or weakening it to a vowel more like the "i" in "hit".